# Two similar services, two IPs, one server?

Tags: networking, centos, firewall

I'm running a CentOS 7 box. On this box I have two services which should both be exposed using port 443 for HTTPS traffic. Using a reverse proxy is no option, one service cannot be reconfigured to another port.

This is how I want to solve this: the machine has two IP addresses - let's call them A and B. On A, I want to publish the first service, using port 443. This works fine. On B, I want to publish the other service, by using a forwarded port.

Whatever I do, I always end up by having the first service tied to both IP A and B. Using firewalld, I've created separate zones for each interface, opened port 443 on one service and added a port forward to the other one. To no avail.

It seems like that the application which is stuck at port 443 has precedence over the rules implied by firewalld, could that be the case? And of so, how I can change this? I cannot make any changes to this application, so my fix should be done at the OS / firewall level.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: If you are working with off the shelf software, you should name it.

Answer (score 3):

firewalld cannot accomplish what you are trying to do. The simplest answer is to reconfigure application A to not listen on (presumably) all interfaces. Since you can't do that your other options are to use network namespaces or VMs. In both cases you create a virtual interface, give it an IP, attach the service to it, and bridge it with the physical interface.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you tell a bit more about the namespacing? I'm familiar with netns, yet I don't know how to tie a specific application to a namespace (and Google doesn't seem to be too helpful in this regard). Thanks!

Comment: If the application isn't aware of network namespaces you can run it in a given namespace with `ip netns exec <ns> <cmd>`